# Socket.io Connection Event Not Firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I know that the socket is connected but the event isn't firing. 
Server:

```
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path');

var app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app);


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


/* Socket.io stuff */
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.use(function(socket, next) {
    auth.session(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});

//On socket connection
io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket) {
    console.log("Socket connected");
});

/* Start server */
server.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});


/* Mount routers */
var auth = require('./routes/auth'),
    index = require('./routes/index');

app.use('/', index.router);
app.use('/auth', auth.router);


/* Exports */
module.exports = app;
```

Pug file:

```
html
    head
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/chat.css')
        script(src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js")
        script(type='text/javascript', src='../javascripts/chat.js')
    body
        include nav.pug
        .chat
            .chat-messages
                .chat-message
                    | Alex: Hello There
                .chat-message
                    | Billy: Hello There
            input.chat(type="text", placeholder="enter ur message")
```

Clientside Javascript:

```
 try {
        var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000');

    } catch(e) {
        //Set status to warn user
        console.log(e);
    }
```

I know that the socket is connecting because it there are no returned errors. Also I can manually call `var socket = io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:3000");`
in the console and it returns undefined but the connection event still does not fire. Any idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: I have noticed similar. Only reconnect event is fired.

Comment: Try to change the pug file this way:   `script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")`

Comment: It looks like you used `express-generator` to create your Express app. If so, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734983/run-socket-io-2-0-and-express-4-0-on-the-same-port/44736644#44736644

Comment: DIdn't mean to have the ` - var socket = io.connect();` in the pug file. I removed it. I am still confused at what I need to do to fix this, I followed that other post and still not working.

Comment: What does `http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"`  returns ?

Comment: What does `auth.session` do ?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js returns 304 and auth.session is the express session instance i created in another file